# Problem updating ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 on cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update my ruby in cygwin from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2.I have pasted the ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz into the required folder in the home directory.After that i entered this command.

tar xvf ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz. It is throwing errors while unpacking the file..

This is the a sample of the error i got

**ruby-1.9.2-p136/win32/winmain.c

tar:ruby-1.9.2-p136/win32/winmain.c:Cannot change ownership to uid 501, gid 20:Invalid Argument.**

I got this error on all the files present in rruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz.

Can somebody tell me where i am going wrong and the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)? It removes much of the pain.

Comment: yes it did.I am using ruby on rails on ubuntu right now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: your tarball was packed by userid 501, groupid 20.  When you unpack it, for some reason it's trying to set the userid and groupid of all the files to those, but you don't have that user/group on your system.  It should still unpack though.

As a small test, do something like:

```
tar -tzvf ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz | head
```

and see what the user/group of the files are.  Odd that it's trying to set that on your output files, since you don't include any perm flags for that.

Comment: I have posted the result of  tar -tzvf ruby-1.9.2-p136.tar.gz | head
on the link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959196/problem-updating-ruby-1-8-7-to-1-9-2-on-cygwin].I don't yet have the privelege to post pic o/p on the this site

Comment: can you let me know your comment on this?